# Android Integer as timer wait time

Tags: android, variables, time, timer

I am trying to make timer wait time to change based on users selection. My timer is working but variable for setting time is not. Formula for waiting ime is `((60/bpm)*1000)-190` and for `bpm=60` is give `810` which is correct but when I increase bpm to `61` in application forumla give `-190`. Why?

Timer code:

```
metronomepp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Log.i("Metronome", ""+timetw);
                //timetw=810;
                if(isChecked) {
                    currentTask = new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (metronome.isPlaying()) { metronome.pause(); }
                            metronome.seekTo(0);
                            metronome.start();
                        }
                    };
                    myTimer.schedule(currentTask, 0, timetw); 
                } else {
                    currentTask.cancel();
               }   
        }
    });

Bpm increase and timetw change code:
    plus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
                    bpm++;
                    timetw=(60000/(bpm*1000))-190;
                    Log.i("PlusTW", ""+timetw);
                    Log.i("PlusBPM", ""+bpm);
                    curbpm.setText(""+bpm);
            }
    });
```

Comment: 60/bpm is an integer division. 60/61 = 0. use floats.

Comment: I tryed but it crashed

Comment: define "crashed". and try `timetw=(int) ((60000.0/(bpm*1000.0))-190.0);` That should make the division use floats

Answer (score 1):

Like njzk2 said, you can use floats, and then do `Float.valueOf(float f).intValue()`, which will coerce the float into an int by rounding and truncating. It should work well enough for your purposes.

Comment: But formua gives -190 even when I use float!